# How many reopen _votes_ do we have per day?

Tags: discussion, voting, vote-to-reopen, reopened-questions

1. This question is *not* about the reopen *reviews*, from which we have 20 (in the improbable case of a review queue size > 1000, we would have 40).
2. This question is *not* about the *close votes* (from which we have 24, except SO where we have 50), and also not from the *close reviews*, from which we have 20 (if the queue size >1000, we have 40). Although it seems possible that the reopen votes are handled similarly to the close votes, there is no guarantee for that.

Although most of the reopen votes are cast in the frame of a reopen review, it is not always the case. As we know, reopen votes can be cast also from any reopen view independently. It is not clear, how many time is it possible. I suspect, it could have a similar limit as we have with the close votes.

How many reopen *votes* do we have per day?

Comment: The dupe says: we have 24, except on SO, where we have 50. As I experimentally tested, it is a different count as the close votes: so, we have 24 (50) close votes per day, AND 24 (50) reopen votes per day.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Thanks - then vote them up, it is important, with an upvote you balance 5 downs, but if I get 30 downs and 1 up, it is a loss also to me. At least 20% of the voters should vote up my posts.